# Casting a text to varchar

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I'm attempting to cast a text to a varchar due to a previous issue I had regarding this error message:

```
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator RSS
```

With a quick search, I found that I need to cast the value which is text to that of a varchar. I have done so:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM DeStudent e " +
            "WHERE CAST(e.studentExpression as varchar) = :studentExpression" +
            "AND e.deactivationTime = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000' " +
            "AND (:studentName is null OR e.name = :studentName)" +
            "AND (:studentDescription is null OR e.description = :studentDescription)" +
            "AND (:studentExpression is null OR e.studentExpression = :studentExpression)"
    )
```

However I seem to be getting this error:

```
2020-07-08 14:42:39.947 ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:142: unexpected token: e
```

And it's not allowing me to run the application due to this modification. I'm unsure what I have done, any help? Thank you. I've tried different variations as well, such as moving the cast to the select section but it's still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the issue is with the letter 'e' not being understood. Your select clause is where the issue is. You wrote `SELECT e FROM DeStudent e`, which aliased the DeStudent table as 'e', but the select clause should specify columns, not just 'e'. To select everything, use *.

```
SELECT * FROM DeStudent e
```